# angular2 simple addClass (jquery style)?

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript

i've been struggling with the simplest thing... i need to add a class to a `<div>` when i click on, let's say, a `button`.
I've been looking online and here on stackoverflow for hours and all i can find is some overcomplicated examples with `ngFor`s that i cannot (and i am not able to) deconstruct to fit it to what i need.

I'm looking to achieve something as simple as this (jquery) in angular2/typescript:

```
 $(".button").click(function() {  
    $(".element").addClass("active");      
  });
```

i have a component folder with the usual html,scss, and ts file. this function doesn't need to be global or anything weird.

i can't believe how something as simple as this has become so complicated to achieve with modern frameworks.

any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: imo the best way to achive that would be creating the decorator. Decorator should be added to every element that you want to behave in this way. Decorator will addClass to element using HostListener onClick

Comment: @MaciejWójcik that's a bit overkill and it's assuming you have the need for it on several html elements, which I think isn't the case here

Comment: sure, that depends on the needs (the amount of elements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple. you need to use `ngClass` like this :

```
<button (click)="isActive = true">Your button</button>
<div class="element" [ngClass]="{'active': isActive}"
```

https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Comment: Or even simpler: `[class.active]="isActive"`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not complicated at all : you just do not know where/what to look for.

First solution :

```
<div [class.myClass]="isClicked"></div>
<button (click)="isClicked = true">Click me</button>
```

Second solution

```
<div #myDiv></div>
<button (click)="myDiv.className='myClass'">Click me</button>
```